# dump matching tables php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to dump some of my tables if the prefix of theme is matching a given sub string using php. Trying to use php's `system` did not bring any result in sense the dump file was not created. I thought to use the command line function `exec` to achieve my result and I was making the following

```
 exec('E:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump '. $dbname .' -h '. $this->host .' -u ' .$this->user . ' $(E:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -u '. $this->user . ' -p ' . $dbname .' -Bse "show tables like \'wp_dev%\'")> mydb.sql 2>&1', $output);
```

but to sub query what would filter out the matching tables is returning the following error

```
mysqldump: unknown option '-s'
```

It seems like I'm missing something by the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this, it will take dump of only listed tables.

```
exec('E:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h '. $this->host .' -u ' .$this->user . ' -p'. $this->password .' '. $dbname .' table1 table2  > /path_to_file/dump_file.sql');
```

Comment: and how could I build in this query `"show tables like \'wp_dev%\'"` I would like to dump just the matching tables

Comment: for that I was making something like `$tables ="SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname LIKE 'wp_%'";
        $result = mysql_query($tables); 
          
          $to_dump = array();
          while ($dumped_tables = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
              $to_dump[] = $dumped_tables[0];
             
          }` and trying to use implode. But something I'm missing by mysqldump

Comment: check my updated solution, you have to pass tables name which you want to take backup of, you can use implode(' ', $to_dump); to form string of table names.