# 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mysql-backup

currently im trying to make backup and restore mysql database in my laravel project. I am using this laravel package https://github.com/backup-manager/laravel for backup package. i already follow the intructions, but when i am trying to backup my local database through command line (php artisan db:backup) in the last question, i got this message.

```
Dumping database and uploading...   

[BackupManager\ShellProcessing\ShellProcessFailed]
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I already googling it, and already put C:\xampp\mysql\bin to my windows env variables paths, but i still having this issue. if anybody know how to fix this, please tell me, i really appreciate it.

Laravel 5.1.x

Comment: Open a new command window. Type set. Look at path. Was it updated? Type mysqldump

Comment: Yes, it is updated, But, when i type mysqldump, i got the same message. ('mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

Comment: Cd c:\ then dir mysqldump.exe /s

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: These guys have it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668766/dump-matching-tables-php

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed `mysqldump`

Comment: I thought xampp already have mysqldump in it

Answer (score 26):

It is because **mysqldump.exe is not found** in that location, the right path is given bellow

1. Open **Command Prompt** and type this

   > ***cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin***

Press Enter

then type

> ***mysqldump.exe***

or,

Directly open this directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin" and Press LEFT SHIFT KEY from keyboard and RIGHT CLICK on the Directory Window.
then type

> ***mysqldump.exe***

It will work 100% correctly

Comment: saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [Xamp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) then:

1. Open your Xamp folder
2. Go to \mysql\bin find the mysqldump.exe
3. Go to your environment variables under System variable click on 'New'.
4. As 'variable name' put 'mysqldump'(without the quotes) and as 'variable value' put the path to your xamp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe this will make 'mysqldump' available as a global system alias.

> Reminder: Make sure to restart your command-line interface.

Comment: For Windwos 10: Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables (from Nick's comment to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753133/6266364)

Answer (score 2):

On my side, I was using PowerShell and I had the same error message.
I had to go inside the directory of MySql. Mine was located in:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin

Then I had to make sure that I had `mysqldump.exe` in the bin folder.
[image]

And then run this command:

```
 ./mysqldump.exe -u root -p yordbName > C:\MySqlDump\sakila.sql
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me and I solved it by adding the following line at the top of the .bat file.

cd "C:\xampp\mysql\bin"

Comment: OP is not using a windows batch file but PHP/Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Please add **C:\xampp\mysql\bin** to this path at your user variables and system variables. If you are using a wamp server, add **C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.27\bin** this path at your user and system variables.

**Note: MySQL version path will change as per your installation.**

Answer (score 0):

It is late, but I will answer to this question for other people who have the same issue.

You need to add the mysqldump.exe runtime file path to your Windows environment variable. I am using Wamp, the path look like this "C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysqlx.x.xx\bin"

Close your command-line interface and try again, It should work.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Xamp and the following step is working:

Copy the path "C:\xampp\mysql\bin"
Go to your environment variables under System variable click on 'Path' and add "New".
Put the path there then click ok.
Restart your command-line interface.

Comment: OP explicity stated that he has already tried this.